# Help with the convergence of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that $a,b\geq 0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}}=\max\{a,b\}$

I don't know how to start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Without loss of generality assume that $a\ge b$ and try to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=a$. Note that

$$\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=a\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{b}a\right)^n}\;.$$

Answer (score 5):

Assume without loss of generality that $a\geq b$, so that
$$ a^n\leq a^n+b^n\leq 2a^n $$
for all $n$. Then take $n$th roots of this inequality and use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

For definiteness, first suppose that $a > b$.  Then
$$
a^{n} + b^{n} = a^{n} \, [1 + (b/a)^{n}].
$$
Taking the $n$-th root of this, we get:
$$
a \; \sqrt[n]{1 + (b/a)^{n}}.
$$
Now, the ratio $b/a$ is nonnegative and is strictly less than $1$, and therefore $(b/a)^{n}$ tends to zero as $n \rightarrow +\infty$.  Finally, note that
$$
1 \leq \sqrt[n]{1 + (b/a)^{n}} \leq 1 + (b/a)^{n}.
$$